# How to mock super.ngOnInit() in unit tests with Jasmine? How to create spy on Base / Parent class method to cover derived / child class code only?

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, inheritance, jasmine

```
export class Parent implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit(): void {
    // huge amount of different services calls
    }
}

export class Child extends Parent implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit(): void {
        super.ngOnInit();
        // a few more functions
    }
}
```

How to develop unit test to cover Child's ngOnInit not mocking all services functions for Parent ngOnInit?

My attempts were something like these:

```
let child: Child;
const mockParent = {
    ngOnInit: jasmine.createSpy('ngOnInit')
};
child = new Child();  // base object is created already
Object.getPrototypeOf(child) = jasmine.createSpy('Parent').and.callFake(() => mockParent);  // so this doesn't work
```

Comment: If the child calls super.ngOnInit(), then it seems like its logic depends on that. If you want to write proper test cases, you'll simply need to mock all dependencies.

Comment: parent ngOnInit is covered by unit tests already. Why should I do it again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a solution how to spy parent class function.

```
Parent.prototype.ngOnInit = jasmine.createSpy('ngOnInit');
```

However the solution is not safe enough. Lets see the example:

```
class Mobile {
    sport: string;
  
    setSport(): void {
        this.sport = 'Football';
    }
}

describe('MobileClass', () => {
    const mobile: Mobile = new Mobile();
  
    it('#setSport', () => {
        mobile.setSport();
        expect(mobile.sport).toBe('Football');
    });
});

class Desktop extends Mobile {
    isFootball: boolean;
  
    setSport(): void {
        super.setSport();
        this.isFootball = this.func(this.sport);
    }
  
    func(sp: string): boolean {
        return sp === 'Football' ? true : false;
    }
}

describe('DesktopClass', () => {
    const desktop: Desktop = new Desktop();
  
    it('#setSport', () => {
        Mobile.prototype.setSport = jasmine.createSpy('setSport');
        desktop.sport = 'Basketball';
  
        desktop.setSport();
        expect(Mobile.prototype.setSport).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(desktop.isFootball).toBe(false);
    });

    it('#func', () => { 
        // 2 cases covered
        ...
    });
});
```

Above we have spy on setSport base class function. Both tests passed successfully.
Now imagine some changes are made in base class, for e.g. 'Football' constant is change to 'Tennis' in the base class and its unit test. In this case unit tests for both classes will pass successfully.

Lets refuse the idea of base class mocking. We will have:

```
describe('DesktopClass', () => {
    const desktop: Desktop = new Desktop();
  
    it('#setSport', () => {
        desktop.setSport();
        expect(desktop.isFootball).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

In the first case both tests passed, but if we change 'Football' to 'Tennis' in the base class and its unit test, now, the test for Desktop will fail.
It is quite common mistake when big teams work on a large project and make changes in a few files but forget about others because unit tests for both passed successfully.

The last I'd like to refer the article ['Mocking is a code smell' by Eric Elliott](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/mocking-is-a-code-smell-944a70c90a6a) especially some quotes:

> What is tight coupling?
>
> Subclass coupling: Subclasses are dependent on the implementation and
> entire hierarchy of the parent class: the tightest form of coupling
> available in OO design.
>
> What causes tight coupling?
>
> Mutation vs immutability, Side-Effects vs purity/isolated side-effects, etc.

Keeping base class calls violates in some point of view the term of **unit** test and can require much more mocks for services used in base class. And we'll need to move those mocks in separate file to keep DRY. Think over twice what to choose: faster simpler code or additional insurance against bugs.